# SQL RANK() window function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like this:

```
question_id    message_id    responder
          1             1    user_a
          1             2    user_b
          1             3    user_b
          1             4    user_a
```

I currently have `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY question_id, responder ORDER BY message_id)` but that produces this:

```
question_id    message_id    responder    rank()
          1             1    user_a            1
          1             2    user_b            1
          1             3    user_b            2
          1             4    user_a            2
```

Desired output:

```
question_id    message_id    responder    rank()
          1             1    user_a            1
          1             2    user_b            2
          1             3    user_b            2
          1             4    user_a            3
```

Comment: What's the logic? Why us user_b ranked `2` twice in the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are wanting to tracking when the user id changes when ordered by message id. Which is what [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html) does for you

```
CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(responder) OVER (PARTITION BY question_id ORDER BY message_id) b
```